Add Probability/Chance of measuring qubit to qiskit circuit drawing
I am new to using Qiskit to design quantum circuit. My prior experience has been to use Quirk Example to simulate and analyse circuits.

One feature that I really like about Quirk is it's ability to show the chance of a qubit being measured "ON" or 1.
Qiskit allows me to design circuits and simplify it by giving the circuit and the qubits "names" which can be displayed in the circuit diagram. I was wondering if there was a way to display the "chance" of measuring "1" on each qubit wire, similar to what Quirk offers?
